# How to restore previous version of saved query?

Tags: google-bigquery

I worked on a saved query (saved under the main project and not private), and the last save was a mistake. How can I restore the last save?

Yes I know "*You can go into your query history for that project and retrieve all your queries from the last few months.*", but it includes lots of queries with modifications and it can take me a whole day. Is there another way?

Comment: . . I can appreciate that.  I suffer a worse problem which is that I write queries in many projects.  I think there is a search functionality.  And you can use the time on the query.  I tend to stash queries in a spreadsheet.  That is an old habit that has worked across many different databases (and spreadsheets).

Answer (score 0):

This answer was provided by @Gordon Linoff in the comment section:

> I think there is a search functionality. And you can use the time on
>   the query. I tend to stash queries in a spreadsheet. That is an old
>   habit that has worked across many different databases (and
>   spreadsheets).